# Jupyter on VScode doesn't work with pyenv+poetry

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a new Jupyter notebook in VScode. This is what I did so far:

Step 1: installed VScode Jupyter extension.
Step 2: created a virtual environment using pyenv.
Step 3: installed jupyter using poetry.

Maybe not relevant, but I also selected the virtual environment's interpreter using the command palette command `Python: Select Interpreter`.

The issue is that the command `Create: New Jupyter Notebook` is missing from the command palette (attached below). I also tried the `Select Interpreter to Start Jupyter Server` command but nothing happens.

[image]

Also, If I run `jupyter lab` in the terminal, create a new notebook and then open the file again in VScode's file explorer, I see a JSON-like file rather than the familiar look of a Jupyter notebook.

**VScode**
Version: 1.85.2 (Universal)
Commit: 8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681
Date: 2024-01-18T06:40:32.531Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 26354273
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0

**Mac**
Apple M1 Pro 14.2.1
OS: Darwin arm64 23.2.0

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install jupyter to your environment? Did you activate it? Are you able to run `jupyter notebook` or, more preferably, `python -m jupyter notebook` in your poetry shell?

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks for the reply. I installed Jupyter using poetry so it's installed into my pyenv environment and I'm able to run `python -m jupyter notebook`...

Comment: any relation to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78097487/11107541 ?

Comment: Have you installed the [Jupyter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter) extension? Also show your problem interface.

Comment: @starball I don't think so since I don't have an issue with resolving the imports. In terms of virtualenv and dependencies, seems like everything is set up just fine and VScode recognizes it.

Comment: @JialeDu Yeah it's installed.

Comment: Describe your specific problem in detail, preferably showing the steps and interface. Also 
`Python: Select Interpreter` has nothing to do with jupyter, it doesn't affect jupyte anything.  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @JialeDu I edited the post. Any specific details/interface shots that are missing?